Any better alternatives to bullet connectors for connecting outdoor antenna wires?
I build antennas and sometimes have a need to repeatedly connect and disconnect wire antenna elements, such as loading coils and radials. It is especially the case for portable antennas.
I have been using crimp-on "bullet" connectors that have a male and female part, and they seem to work fine. At most I run 100 W. For safety, I like the idea that with enough force, they will come apart although there is a lot of variation in the amount of force required.
I am planning to build another portable antenna and am thinking about this. Have you had problems with bullet connectors, or is there any other type of connector you have used and have been happy with? They don't necessarily need to be in-line connections, and I have used screw terminals which I think provide a more certain connection but are more time consuming.

Choosing a connector is really about prioritizing the considerations for your use case and needs.
For example, if long lasting and weatherproof for permanent installation is the application, perhaps a crimped and soldered connection covered with weatherproofing sleeve is appropriate.
For your stated use-case, portable setup and take down, coupled with an appreciation of the in-built mechanical-impulse safety afforded by bullet connectors, you seem to be in a good spot already.
